# latex dynamic subsection nesting

Tags: nesting, sectioning

I need to find a command/environment that allows me to nest a [sub]section one level deeper than the level of the parent [sub]section.

For example, given this syntax,

```
\section{Foo}
    \createanestedsection{Bar}
\subsection{Zoo}
    \createanestedsection{Bar}
```

I'd like to obtain this output:

```
1. ...... Foo
1.1 ..... Bar
1.2 ..... Zoo
1.2.1 ... Bar
```

Is there anything like that available ?

Regards, R

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
(La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: Interesting, but to be useful you need a command to enter a nested level and another one to leave the nested level.

Comment: You may use the answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31010/17424 and play with the index of the `\level` command (+1 when nested). Or am I off-topic ?

Comment: @alfc I understand your intent, but a `\section` *et al.* are not environments, but merely macros.  Thus, there is no need to "leave" anything, but merely to issue the macro one level down from the current level.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\newcommand{\nestasection}[1]{
\ifnum \thesubsection >0
    \subsubsection{#1}
\else
    \ifnum \thesection >0
        \subsection{#1}
    \else
        \section{#1}
    \fi
\fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The various section commands in LaTeX are designed to do just what you ask for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

\section{Zoo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsubsection{Baz}
\paragraph{Moo}

\section{Loo}
\subsection{Boo}

\end{document}
```

[image]