# Additional sectioning levels above book

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am using `memoir` which currently supports book, part, chapter, section, subsection, etc... I would like an additional layer above this (say "volume") which behaves well (numbered and appears in a table of contents).

I have come across this question [More section headings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30997/more-section-headings) which helps produce levels below the default ones but I am struggling to reverse this procedure.

Comment: You have at least two options: Copy whatever is involved with `\book` over into a new macro called `\volume`, or create `\volume` from scratch. Since you don't present any details in terms of the look/feel/interaction of `\volume` compared to the rest of the document, at best an answer would most likely copy `\book` into `\volume`. It's still a lot of work though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [basic user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (section **6.2 SECTIONAL DIVISIONS**, p 74):

> A `\section` command restarts the numbering of any `\subsections` from one. For
>   most of the divisions the `<title>` is put on the page where the command was issued. The
>   `\book`, `\part` and `\chapter` commands behave a little differently.
>
> The `\book` and `\part` commands are simpler and both behave in the same way.
>   The `\book{<title>}` command puts the book name (default `Book`), number and `<title>` on
>   a page by itself. The numbering of books has no effect on the numbering of `\part`s or
>   `\chapter`s.

We can make an entire copy of `\book`, and call it `\volume`, and it'll react in the same way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}% Just for this example
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% Just for this example

\makeatletter
\newcounter{volume} \setcounter{volume}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thevolume}{\@Roman\c@volume}
\newcommand*{\theHvolume}{\arabic{volume}}
\newcommand*{\toclevel@volume}{-3}
\newcommand*{\volume}{%
  \@setupvolume
  \secdef\@volume\@svolume}
\newcommand*{\beforevolumeskip}{\null\vfil}
\newcommand*{\midvolumeskip}{\par\vskip 2\onelineskip}
\newcommand*{\aftervolumeskip}{\vfil\newpage}
\newcommand{\@setupvolume}{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{volume}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \beforevolumeskip}
\newcommand*{\volumename}{Volume}
\newcommand*{\volumenamefont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\newcommand*{\volumenumfont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\newcommand*{\volumetitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\newcommand*{\printvolumename}{\volumenamefont \volumename}
\newcommand*{\volumenamenum}{\space}
\newcommand*{\printvolumenum}{\volumenumfont \thevolume}
\newcommand*{\printvolumetitle}[1]{\volumetitlefont #1}
\newcommand{\memvolumeinfo}[3]{}
\newcommand{\memvolumestarinfo}[1]{}
\long\def\@volume[#1]#2{%
  \M@gettitle{#1}%
  \def\f@rtoc{#1}%
  \@nameuse{volume@f@rtoc@before@write@hook}%
  \phantomsection
  \mempreaddvolumetotochook
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-4\relax
    \refstepcounter{volume}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{volume}%
      {\protect\volumenumberline{\thevolume}\f@rtoc}%
    \memvolumeinfo{\thevolume}{\f@rtoc}{#2}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{volume}{\f@rtoc}%
    \memvolumeinfo{}{\f@rtoc}{#2}%
  \fi
  \mempostaddvolumetotochook
  \volumepagemark{#1}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \parskip\z@
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-4\relax
     \printvolumename \volumenamenum \printvolumenum
     \midvolumeskip
   \fi
   \printvolumetitle{#2}\par}%
  \@endvolume}
\newcommand\mempreaddvolumetotochook{}
\newcommand\mempostaddvolumetotochook{}
\long\def\@svolume#1{%
  \M@gettitle{#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \memvolumestarinfo{#1}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \parskip\z@
   \normalfont
   \printvolumetitle{#1}\par}%
  \@endvolume}
\newif\ifm@mnovolumenewpage
  \m@mnovolumenewpagefalse
\newcommand*{\volumeblankpage}{\m@mnovolumenewpagefalse}
\newcommand*{\novolumeblankpage}{\m@mnovolumenewpagetrue}
\newcommand*{\volumepageend}{\aftervolumeskip
  \ifm@mnovolumenewpage
  \else
    \if@twoside
      \if@openright
        \null
        \thispagestyle{aftervolume}%
        \newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}
\def\@endvolume{\volumepageend}
\aliaspagestyle{volume}{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{aftervolume}{empty}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumebreak}{\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
  \addvspace{\cftbeforevolumeskip}}
\newcommand*{\l@volume}[2]{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth >-4\relax
    \cftvolumebreak
    \begingroup
      {%
       \memRTLleftskip \cftvolumeindent\relax
       \memRTLrightskip \@tocrmarg
       \parfillskip -\memRTLrightskip
       \parindent \cftvolumeindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
       \interlinepenalty\@M
       \leavevmode
       \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\cftvolumefont\cftvolumename}%
       \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\cftvolumenumwidth}%
       \let\@cftbsnum \cftvolumepresnum
       \let\@cftasnum \cftvolumeaftersnum
       \let\@cftasnumb \cftvolumeaftersnumb
       \advance\memRTLleftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\memRTLleftskip
       {\cftvolumefont {#1}}%
       \cftvolumefillnum{#2}}
      \nobreak
      \global\@nobreaktrue
      \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\volumenumberlinehook[1]{}
\newcommand{\volumenumberline}[1]{%
  \volumenumberlinehook{#1}%
  \volumenumberlinebox\@tempdima{%
    \cftvolumename\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum}\@cftasnumb}%%\space}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumename}{}
\newcommand*{\volumepagemark}[1]{}
\let\volumenumberlinebox\mem@cft@hb@xt@
\newlength{\cftbeforevolumeskip}
  \setlength{\cftbeforevolumeskip}{2.25em \@plus\p@}
\newdimen\cftvolumeindent
  \setlength{\cftvolumeindent}{0em}
\newdimen\cftvolumenumwidth
  \setlength{\cftvolumenumwidth}{1.5em}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumefont}{\large\bfseries}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumepresnum}{}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumeaftersnum}{}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumeaftersnumb}{}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumeleader}{%
  \large\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftvolumedotsep}}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumedotsep}{\cftnodots}
\newcommand*{\cftvolumepagefont}{\large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\cftvolumeafterpnum}{}
\newcommand{\cftvolumefillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftvolumeleader}%
  \cftvolumeformatpnum{#1}%
  \cftvolumeafterpnum\par}
\newcommand{\cftvolumeformatpnumhook}[1]{}
\newcommand{\cftvolumeformatpnum}[1]{%
  \cftvolumeformatpnumhook{#1}%
  \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss {\cftvolumepagefont #1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\volume{A volume}
\book{A book}
\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Werner. Thank you very much for your help! I very much appreciate the time you took to help me out on this :)