# full numbering of all section divisions for outline

Tags: sectioning

we are using latex as an "outline" producer.  that is, we are first building a document skeleton with lots of levels.

```
\section{idea}
\subsection{subidea}
\subsubsection{subsubidea}
\subsubsubsection{subsubsubidea}
\subsubsubsubsection{subsubsubsubidea}
```

this is our "thought organization phase."   it doesn't even need to stop with 5 sub levels.  it could go down even lower, though 6-8 is probably a hard limit.  we are reusing the ordinary names, though something like \header[3]{...} instead of \subsubsection{} would work equally well.

eventually (but not for a while), when we move to our "text writing phase," the text from the lowest level headings will be used for guidance of what to write into the text and the lowest levels will disappear.  at this point, we want to flip the switch and use the ordinary latex formatting.

ideally, in the org phase, until we get to the writing phase, we want this to print as

```
1. idea
1.1 subidea
1.1.1 subsubidea
1.1.1.1 subsubsubidea
1.1.1.1.1. subsubsubsubidea
```

and of course with suitable number resets. (subsubsub is reset when subsub appears, etc.).  some style (sizing, spacing) would be nice, but it probably shouldn't be as aggressive as in ordinary latex documents.

has someone already thrown together a style for this?  I looked on ctan but couldn't find one.

pointers appreciated.

regards, /iaw

Comment: well apart from the default depth which is 5 in the standard classes, doesn't `article` do this already? (just increase secnumdepth and reduce it when you don't want them numbered)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i think that you but he was egreg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30997/more-section-headings

Comment: @touhami he'll do anything to get a tick:-)