# Exporting indefinitely deep org trees

Tags: sectioning, org-mode

I would like to export to LaTeX from EMACS's Org mode but with
indefinitely many levels.  Is this possible?

By default there are only 5 levels

```
'("article" "\\documentclass[11pt]{article}"
 ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
 ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
 ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
 ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
 ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
```

It would also be nice to dispense with differentiated formatting in
headings.  Ideally, I would like all level headings to have the normal
font size and be formatted like this:

> *3.141 Heading*

Perhaps normal sectioning commands can be avoided altogether.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31010/1090

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `article` class has six levels --- you forgot `\part`. The `memoir` class provides eight levels: `\book`, \part`, \chapter`, `\section` and so on. I think that, in general seven levels are enough, from `\part` to `\subsubparagraph` but `\part` is not often needed.

Again, I don't think that it is a good idea to have all the division headings use the same font and size, then the only differentiation is the numbering scheme rather than numbering and visual display.